# Want to know how to bind a map type column in a prepared insert statement in Cassandra with php drivers

Tags: cassandra, datastax-php-driver

Can someone please help me with the exact syntax to use prepared insert / update statements containing map type columns.
suppose :

```
UPDATE abc SET map = map + ? where id = ?
```

where map is the map type column,

I found an answer 
Cassandra prepared statements with collections
but it just contained the syntax to generate a particular map type object rather binding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute it as usual for prepared queries, but you need to pass `Cassandra::Map` object as first parameter, something like this:

```
 $statement = $session->prepare('....')
 $map = Cassandra\Type::map(Cassandra\Type::varchar(), Cassandra\Type::int())
       ->create('a', 1);
 $id = 'something'
 $session->execute($statement, array('arguments' => array($map, $id)));
```

You need to pass `Map` object because [CQL's appending to the map expects](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertMap.html) another map as an argument.

Comment: One last thing,If I want to do map - key,val how would I do that?

Comment: I don’t understand question... can you explain